# Using Capybara along with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, capybara

I'm trying to write a Sign in integration test for my app + devise by using Capybara.

Here is what I have so far:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "the signup process", :type => :request do
  before :each do
    @user_1 = Factory.create(:user, :email => 'bob@golden.com', :password => 'iPassword')
  end

  it "signs me in" do

    visit new_user_session_path

    fill_in 'user[email]', :with => 'bob@golden.com'
    fill_in 'user[password]', :with => 'iPassword'

    click_link_or_button 'Sign In'

  end


end
```

This is passing. Problem here is that it isn't checking that the user was signed in (cookie?) and that the url redirected correctly?

How can I add those details to this test? Also for an invalid login, how can I test to make sure the flash alert was set correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After click_link_or_button 'Sign In' add:

```
current_path.should == 'your path'
page.should have_content("Signed in successfully.")
```

/support/devise.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at the logs. For some reason it is redirecting to example.com any ideas?

Comment: Do you have devise.rb? Added to answer.

Comment: I just added that to: spec/support/devise.rb which did not exist before. trying now

Comment: done... stackoverflow makes you wait several minutes. I really hate that